# Using an old router as switch and access point

Tags: networking, switch, dhcp-server

I have an old router that I would like to repurpose as a switch and as a access point.

I did the following steps according to guides I've found online:

My home networks router IP is 10.0.0.138 And it's DHCP server distributes from 10.0.0.1-32

On the old router I did the following:

1. Changed its IP to 137 (10.0.0.137)
2. Disabled its DHCP server
3. Connected the old router to the home router via LAN cable

Problem is: Some devices that connect to the switch via wifi - get a valid IP in the range and are successfully connected to the home network.

But: some devices cannot connect to the switch as they are waiting for an IP and getting a weird one starting at 169.254.x.x

This happens to devices connected only via WiFi, machines connected via Ethernet cable seem to not have that problem.

This presents a strange problem as if only X devices are allowed to be connected to the switch.

Old router model: DLink dsl-2760U

What is my problem? Did I miss a step ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like those devices with the 169.254.~ addresses cannot talk to the DHCP server. Maybe try flashing the firmware of the router or seeing the wi-fi NIC in those devices are compatible with the router signal bands.

Comment: That sounds like the DHCP server in the D-Link isn't really fully disabled and still intercepts some of the DHCP requests (even though it isn't supplying any ip-addresses). I have seen that before. If that is the case it is a firmware problem that is not solvable by yourself. A firmware update on the D-Link may help.