# Unable to configure Zyxel VMG1312-B30B router as switch on 192.-like network

Tags: networking, router, switch, ip-address

I have an old unused Zyxel VMG1312-B30B router and I am trying to use it as switch in home network to extend it to the attic.
Since it has 4 RJ45 ports, I want to use 1 port as incoming from main home router and remaining 3 are enough at the moment.

I am developer and not network specialist though I am aware of difference between router and switch and basic configuration.
I have read tons of howtos on the web (for example [1](https://www.howtogeek.com/174419/how-to-reuse-your-old-wi-fi-router-as-a-network-switch/), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1244587/using-an-old-router-as-switch-and-access-point), [3](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-use-an-old-router-as-a-switch-without-internet-access-ports-How-would-that-be-possible)) and made lot of attempts. To configure old router as switch, I reset it to factory settings, connect it to standalone notebook, enter admin interface on 10.0.0.138 and do configuration changes: disabling DHCP, Wifi, firewall and changing IP address to 192.168.1.4 (main network is 192.168.1.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and I verified the IP address is not used; alternatively I narrowed the DHCP range on main router from 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254 to 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.253 and assigned IP 192.168.1.254 to Zyxel).

After IP address change, the router admin interface (naturally) stops communication on 10.0.0.138 but *does not start communication on new 192.168.1.4 address*.
However if new address is 10.-like, say 10.0.0.137, the admin interface works.

Is there some possibility that router whose factory local IP address is class A is not reconfigurable to class C IP address? Or is it likely the hardware or firmware problem? What could I do to better diagnostic what's happening here?

Comment: Did you reconfigure the notebook to be on the new subnet?

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/zyxel/zyxel-vmg1312-b10d/faq/repeater-mode/router-as-repeater/) the router should have AP Mode or Repeater Mode (or perhaps extender) which should work for you.

Comment: @u1686_grawity The local IP address of notebook was 192... so far hence I think it is on same subnet (I invoked ipconfig to verify). I wonder why it cannot connect to other device with 192... IP address and why it can connect to device with 10... IP address.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately your post is about B30D router, mine is B30B. The B30D router has WAN RJ45 port, repeater mode and default factory IP address 192..., neither of which applies to my router.

Comment: Perhaps your router manual is [this one](http://download.from.zyxel.ru/4858c16b-4233-4923-ad4e-c362aff1efca/VMG1312-B10B_B30B%20Series_UG_V1-00_Ed1.pdf). It does have for DHCP a "Relay" mode, and for wired/wireless a Bridged mode. These are the modes that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not bother with the IP address configuration if it's not working. It's not needed for switch functionality at all – the switch just forwards packets based on MAC address (and the router's IP configuration doesn't come into play until there's a packet specifically addressing the router's MAC). So as long as you can prevent it from serving DHCP and UPnP, that will be enough, and if you ever need to reconfigure the device you'll just temporarily do the PC settings like you're doing now.

> Is there some possibility that router whose factory local IP address is class A is not reconfigurable to class C IP address?

Technically possible but unlikely, as classful addressing was abandoned a good two decades before this router's release. It's more likely to be some other generic kind of failure.

(Even in hardware that had remnants of classful addressing, the biggest restriction was that you could only do subnets but not supernets of a classful network (e.g. within 192.168 you could do a /29 but not a /23). But your 192.168.1.0/24 is exactly the dimensions of a "class C" network, so even old class-based hardware would not have minded.)